# CakePHP - success with $hasOne, failure with $hasMany

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-model

Good morning,

I am having trouble with $hasMany, even though $hasOne works fine.

I have two models, Assignment and AssignmentGroup. Assignment can have one AssignmentGroup but AssignmentGroup can have many Assignments. Here are the relationships:

```
class Assignment extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array('AssignmentGroup');
}

class AssignmentGroup extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Assignment' => array('foreignKey'=>'assignment_group_id),
    );
}
```

Here's the code I'm running:

```
$this->AssignmentGroup->Behaviors->load('Containable');
$params = array(
    'conditions' => array('AssignmentGroup.class_id' => $class_id),
    'contain' => array('Assignment'),
);
$result = $this->AssignmentGroup->find('all', $params);
```

When I use $hasOne instead of $hasMany I get the expected result.

```
$result = array(
    'AssignmentGroup => array(
        [several elements]
    ),
    'Assignment' => array(
        [more elements]
    ),
);
```

However, when I use $hasMany, as I need to, things fall apart. The query does not have a JOIN.

```
$result = array(
    'AssignmentGroup => array(
        [several elements]
    ),
    'Assignment' => array(),
);
```

Can anyone explain what's going on and/or suggest a solution? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with CakePHP, but shouldn the foreign key be in the Assignment model?

Comment: did you get it working?  I am having the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37946705/cakephp-2-8-4-ignoring-hasmany

Answer (score 1):

This might be minor, but I always make sure that I use `className` in the Model definition.

```
var $hasMany = array(
    'Assignment' => array(
        'className' => 'Assignment',
        'foreignKey' => 'assignment_group_id',
    ),
);
```

Just to be safe since the book does say "aliases for each model must be unique app wide" it helps me keep those straight.

Also, try using the `$hasMany` but taking the `contain` out just to see if that could be what's messing you up.

Comment: I made all your suggested changes (with recursive = 1) but the Assignment array is still empty.

Comment: You may need the `foreignKey` key inside the `$belongsTo` array as well. Since (per the book) "The default value for this key is the underscored, singular name of the other model, suffixed with _id."

However, I noticed that your model name is `AssignmentGroup` but your key is `assignment_group_id` (with an underscore). That could be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
class AssignmentGroup extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Assignment' => array('foreignKey'=>'assignment_group_id),
    );
}
```

should be:

```
class AssignmentGroup extends AppModel {
public $hasMany = array(
    'Assignment' => array('foreignKey'=>'assignment_group_id' ),
);
}
```