# Cakephp 2.8.4 ignoring hasMany

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, models, cakephp-2.8

This is a very odd issue that I have not been able to figure out for a very long time.

I have a model **Upload**, with several **hasMany** all being ignored by **UploadModel**.

For example. **Upload** hasMany **Face**.

On comments table I have a field called foreign_key that hosts the Upload.id.
So the relationship in UploadModel looks like this:

```
$hasMany = ['Face' => ['foreignKey' => 'Face.upload_id']];
```

When performing a find in Upload with contain Face + conditions **[Face.celebrity_id = 4018]** I get the following error because the query is missing the Left Join to Face:

```
$media = $this->Upload->find('all',array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Face.celebrity_id' => 4018
        ),
        'contain' => array(
            'Face'
        )
    ));

SQL Query: 
SELECT `Upload`.`id`, `Upload`.`user_id`, `Upload`.`filename`, `Upload`.`created` 
FROM `uploads` AS `Upload` 
WHERE `Face`.`celebrity_id` = 4018;

SQL Error:
Unknown column 'Face.celebrity_id' in 'where clause'
```

### **As you can see the query is missing the left joing to Face, that's all the problem**

If instead of in the $hasMany, I add the Face relationship in $belongsTo, it adds the relationship to the query and it works!

But an Upload can have many Faces, and Face.upload_id  has the foreignKey to Upload, so IT NEEDS TO BE A motherf***** HASMANY... lol

---

As you can see, this is terrible, I am already desperate, I have bypassed the issue by adding a bindModel() before each query, but it is totally unnecessary, the hasMany should work!!!!   f****!!!!!

The query that I want Cake to perform for me is this:

```
SELECT `Upload`.`id`, `Upload`.`filename` FROM `uploads` AS `Upload` 
LEFT JOIN `upload_faces` AS `Face` ON (`Upload`.id = `Face`.`upload_id`)
WHERE `Face`.`celebrity_id` = 4018
```

**I appreciate any help, thanks.**

Comment: The same issue here:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12114532/cakephp-success-with-hasone-failure-with-hasmany

Answer (score 0):

ok, so basically, it is not ignoring the hasMany, but I can not use conditions on a hasMany relationship, can only be done if it is a hasOne

Answer (score 0):

In your `test()` function, you run query on `upload` table. So it can not match `Face.celebrity_id` field from your query. Two things you have know first:

1. Condition you are writing in `conditions` clause is applied on the table matching with your model. In your case, `upload` is the table on which query is executed and your table contains no field `Face.celebrity_id`.
2. $hasMany creates application level relations(associations). So by doing query like you have written in `test()` function, it doesn't join the query results.

What you can do is,

```
$this->find('all', array(  
    'contain' => array(
    'Face' => array('conditions' => 'Face.celebrity_id = 4018'))))
```

This will return all rows of `upload` table with associated row of `face` table if `celebrity_id` is `4018`, otherwise `null` array.

Hope this will help you and if you want that only those many rows will be returned which are associated with `Face.celebrity_id = 4018`, first you have to run query on `face` table and then another on first query result.

For more detail of second case you can refer [this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html).

Comment: I think I did not explain my self properly. But I consider this a Cakephp issue, or an issue in my model, because you can use a condition on a JOINED model, I have done it before, SQL example:

SELECT `Upload`.`id`, `Upload`.`filename` FROM `uploads` AS `Upload` 
LEFT JOIN `upload_faces` AS `Face` ON (`Upload`.id = `Face`.`upload_id`)
WHERE `Face`.`celebrity_id` = 4018

Comment: may be should try this: [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/a/18116633/5260631) and if you are not clear about your question first, then you should ask for solution exactly required. Down voting answer is not the thing you should do, when your question is ambiguous.

Comment: I am sorry, the question has been shortened just to try to get more answers. That does not mean that it was not clear before, I was just trying to be polite. Actually at the beginning there was more information as I am sure you remember.    The negative vote is probably too much yes.